# Where are the LRS Snapshots - Standard HDD Managed Disks

Tags: azure

I am trying to use Microsoft Azure.
I saw the snapshots over the limit in the Cost Management + Billing | Overview

> LRS Snapshots - Standard HDD Managed Disks 246% 2.46 / 1 1 GB/Month

[image]

Disks https://portal.azure.com/#blade/HubsExtension/BrowseResourceBlade/resourceType/Microsoft.Compute%2Fdisks

> ddd202004261050
>   Premium SSD
>   1024 GiB
>   ddd
>   a
>   West US

Disks (classic)

> none

Snapshots https://portal.azure.com/#blade/HubsExtension/BrowseResourceBlade/resourceType/Microsoft.Compute%2Fsnapshots

> none

I can't find HDD disks please help me to find the resource.

Answer (score 1):

The snapshots which you are referring to are LRS snapshots for Managed disks, There are two possibilities why you are seeing this in your Bill.

You managed machine is under Azure VM Backup or it has a snapshot created which is incurring cost.

To check the snapshots available on the global search type Snapshot:

[Global search image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCbCb.png)

If the snapshots are visible, click on one of them and read "Source disk" property under Overview tab. That should tell you the parent disk.

If there are no snapshots, that means the charge is coming from Azure VM based backups.